# xcodebuild command not working properly with dynamic cocoa touch framework

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, xcodebuild

I have created dynamic framework and added to my project with .xcodeproj file. Also added the dynamic framework to 'Embedded Binaries'. I build this project using Xcode and it is working fine. After that I tried to build project using 'xcodebuild' command, it failed to build and gave me error as no such module 'my_module'.

My both project folder (main folder & dynamic framework project) is on the same directory level. I don't have a workspace for both project.

Please help me, why I am not able to build the project using 'xcodebuild' command?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Build Settings** and search **Framework Search Paths**.

If the frameworks are placed in your project directory, then set the framework search path to `$(SRCROOT)` and set it to `recursive`.

Comment: Thanks @Balasubramanian, already tried this. Tried with both project setting as well as target setting. It is not working.